# Which IDE can detect method1 from class1 object by inheritance?

Tags: php, cakephp, ide, extends

I am beginning CakePHP, but I need IDE for detect method of class that have 2 level extends.

I need IDE that detect method1 from class1 object.

Comment: class class1 extends class2{
}
class class2 extends class3{
}
class class3 {
function method1(){
your code is here
}
}

Comment: Just edit your own post, there's no need to add a comment. Also see the help for adding formatted code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NetBeans replaces the line number of method declarations with an indicator when a method is either overriding a method in another class or overridden by a method in another class.

Clicking it takes you to the line of the indicated method declaration in the other class.

[image: NetBeans override indicator]

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://www.tiplite.com/cakephp-support-in-netbeans/) and [here](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/SymenTimmermans/2009/01/21/model-based-code-insight-and-completion-in-netbeans) for some good tips on getting [Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) to recognise relations nicely.